# How to link native library to react native application and what is the folder structure?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build simple app to creative native library and link with react native app.
I am facing issue like
Error : Unable to resolve module `react-native-fingerprint` from `App.js`: react-native-fingerprint could not be found within the project.

Note : 'react-native-fingerprint' which is been created and want to link with app.

[image: below is the screen shot of my project structure , Folder "FingerPrint" is library , Folder "FingerPrintTest" is app "]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using `react-native-fingerprint-scanner`. Since library you mentioned doesn't exist.

In case if you using this library `react-native-fingerprint-scanner`.

**Installation**

```
npm install react-native-fingerprint-scanner --save
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-fingerprint-scanner
```

Link to Native Platforms

```
react-native link react-native-fingerprint-scanner
```

Even after this it is not working. Following this [guide](https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner#readme)

Comment: Hi ,i am not using any npm library , this is the custom  library which i created .. want to link with react native app.